# PostgreSQLで複合主キーで使用されているカラムに外部キーを設定する方法

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL9.4で複合主キーに設定されているカラムに外部キー制約が設定されたテーブルをCREATEしたいと思っているのですが、どのようにすればよいのでしょうか？

現状、以下のようなSQLを使っています

```
-- attend
create table attend (
  room_id bigint not null,
  FOREIGN KEY (room_id) REFERENCES rooms(room_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  user_id bigint not null,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  profile_img varchar(255) not null, -- 冗長だけどパフォーマンス考え

  PRIMARY KEY (room_id, user_id)
);
```

実行環境はPlayframework2.3.8でplay-flywayのマイグレーション実行時にSQLのエラーが出ています

Comment: 実現したいことはそのSQLの通りではないのですか？

Comment: ↑のSQLでテーブルが作れないとエラーが出てしまいます。

Comment: バージョンはちょっと違いますが、9.3では動くようです（http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/256d8/1）。psqlコマンドで実行してもエラーになりますか？

Comment: 返信遅れてしまいました。使用しているPostgreSQLのバージョンが古かったようです。

Answer (score 1):

バージョンはちょっと違いますが、9.3では動くようです。

**動作サンプル:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/256d8/1

```sql
create table rooms(room_id bigint primary key);
create table users(user_id bigint primary key);
create table attend (
  room_id bigint not null,
  FOREIGN KEY (room_id) REFERENCES rooms(room_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  user_id bigint not null,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  profile_img varchar(255) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (room_id, user_id)
);
```

```sql
insert into rooms values (1);
insert into users values (1);
insert into attend values (1, 1, '');

select * from attend;
```

---

<sup>この投稿は @unarist さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9238/postgresql%e3%81%a7%e8%a4%87%e5%90%88%e4%b8%bb%e3%82%ad%e3%83%bc%e3%81%a7%e4%bd%bf%e7%94%a8%e3%81%95%e3%82%8c%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b%e3%82%ab%e3%83%a9%e3%83%a0%e3%81%ab%e5%a4%96%e9%83%a8%e3%82%ad%e3%83%bc%e3%82%92%e8%a8%ad%e5%ae%9a%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95#comment8378_9238)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>